# How can I pass a value to the `filter` function with a pipe without the curly brackets?

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

How can I pass a value to the `filter` function with a pipe without using curly brackets?

```r
library(dplyr)
4 %>% {filter(mtcars, cyl == .)} # Works
```

```r
4 %>% filter(mtcars, cyl == .) # Does not work
```

```r
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Comment: Then my next question is: why? You already have (not merely “a”, but in fact) *the* specific solution to your problem. What’s wrong with it?

Comment: The problem is that it shifts the indentation, so it's not pretty

Comment: “it shifts the indentation” — that’s an editor issue, and I’m not sure what you mean: neither Vim nor RStudio changes the indentation when using curly braces around the RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use an anonymous function

```r
4 %>% (\(.) filter(mtcars, cyl == .))

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can’t.

The semantics of the ‘magrittr’ pipe are such that the LHS is inserted as the first argument of the RHS *unless* `.` is used at the top level of an argument. That is,

```
x %>% f(...)
```

is *always* equivalent to

```
f(x, ...)
```

unless `...` contains `.` at the top level.

To suppress this behaviour, `%>%` specifically provides the `{…}` syntax which you’re already aware of.